# Multiple hideshow regexes

Tags: emacs

In emacs, is there a way to get hideshow-mode to recognize multiple regular expressions for hiding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HideShow). If I'm understanding your question right you may be out of luck however "no simple way" might mean there is a complicated way out there to be found.

Good luck

> There is no simple way to specify
>   multiple regexp pairs for a single
>   language, e.g.,
>
> ```
> * Open: {, close: }
> * Open: #ifdef, close: #else or #elif or … etc.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean in the same mode. This can be done but it will require some elisp and some minor regexp. You will either need to have or create a method of detecting what sub-mode you're in.

Lets take mhtml-mode(HTML/CSS/JS) for example:

```
;;; .emacs

;; When called this automatically detects the submode at the current location.
;; It will then either forward to end of tag(HTML) or end of code block(JS/CSS).
;; This will be passed to hs-minor-mode to properly navigate and fold the code.
(defun mhtml-forward (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (pcase (get-text-property (point) `mhtml-submode)
    (`nil (sgml-skip-tag-forward 1))
    (submode (forward-sexp))))

;; Adds the tag and curly-brace detection to hs-minor-mode for mhtml.
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             '(mhtml-mode
               "{\\|<[^/>]*?"
               "}\\|</[^/>]*[^/]>"
               "<!--"
               mhtml-forward
               nil))
```

The function `mhtml-forward` detects what type of forwarding statement should be used.

Hideshow is then set to recognize the opening expressions `{` and `<tag>`, and the closing expressions `}` and `</tag>`. It will always match the correct one because the custom forwarding function gets you to the correct closing expression for that particular instance.